# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity - Hibernate, SpringBoot, DTO pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, dto

I am trying to build a simple `SpringBoot` and `Hibernate` app using `DAO` and `DTO` pattern.

I am trying to save a list of users to the database.

When I am using `User` class it works fine, but when I am trying to use DTO `CreateUserDto` class I am getting the following error:

`"Unknown entity: com.app.sportapp.dto.CreateUserDto; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.app.sportapp.dto.CreateUserDto"`

There is a `SingleTable` inheritance where `Player class` and `Coach class` inherit `User class`.

**User.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "Users")
@ApiModel(description = "All details about user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "User_Type", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class User implements Seriaalizable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;   
    private String lastName;    
    private String username;    
    private String email;    
    private String password;   
    private String contactNumber;
}
```

**Player.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "Players")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "player")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Player extends User {...}
```

**Coach.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Coaches")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "coach")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Coach extends User{

}
```

And here are DTO's:

**CreateUserDto.java**

```
public class CreateUserDto {...}
```

**PlayerDto.java**

```
public class PlayerDto extends CreateUserDto{...}
```

**CoachDto.java**

```
public class CoachDto extends CreateUserDto{


}
```

As I am very new to `DAO` and `DTO` pattern from error I am getting I assume that it is expected to have a model with `@Entity` called `CreateUser` so same name as DTO `CreateUserDto`? Or can I have the example what I did to have a `User` model and create a new `CreateUserDto`?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are already defining some entities, why do you need the dtos?

Comment: You think I should use it just for displaying user information and not for creation of user?

Comment: DTOs should be used for passing the data from FE to BE and other way around. But you also need converters to convert from one to other. When saving you save entity and not a DTO. 

e.g. FE sends a DTO, you copy properties to entity and use the repo to save entity

Comment: @user9347049 This is my personal opinion and it really depends from your app. But if your DTOs look exactly like your entities, I don't see how having multiple copies of the same classes helps. As far as I can tell, a detached entity behaves the same as a DTO. But it really depends how your application is organised and I suppose others might have different opinions about this.

Comment: @Davide thanks for your answer. So probably when creating new User in the database I should use entities but when retrieving them and displaying DTO's just to send data that is needed.

Comment: You definitely need entities to create a new user in the database with JPA :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you are treating a `DTO` as an entity.
Remove the JPA annotations from the `DTOs` and don't use those classes for connecting to the db.

You will convert the results from your queries from entities to DTO and vice-versa.

I would also suggest to have a look at [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) for the creation of DTO. This will probably make it easier to separate the entities from the DTOs.

Comment: Hi I edited my code. You can take a look at the update in my question. So I removed annotations from my DTO's and added converter using `model mapper`, now I am getting status `200 OK` but when I check database there is no newly created user.

Comment: It's probably because you are not flushing the session or  committing the transaction at the end of the method. Maybe you can add `@Transactional` to the method for example.

Comment: I added new changes added commit transaction to my method and `@Transactional` to my service but still not getting any data in my database. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't mind to help, but you are not supposed to constantly change your question on StackOverflow. My answer was for your original question and it seems it was correct. I think a better place to ask for help in this case is the Spring data room on Gitter: https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-data?source=orgpage

Comment: By the way, the commit should occur after the loop. Not sure what else could be wrong.